# Playwright run tests on multiple servers with different creds

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright

I want to run my playwright tests with multiple credentials simultaneously for different servers. I know that we can parameterise the tests, but not getting the an idea from where to begin? can someone please suggest the good start?